# Symmetric linear system solver

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $m = \mathrm{poly(n)}$ (say $m \geq n^3$), consider the following linear regression problem 
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n } \| A^\top A x - b \|_2.
\end{align*}
The naive method will take $O(m n^2 + n^3) = O(m n^2)$. My question is can we get an $\epsilon$-approximate solution $x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
\| A^\top A x' - b \|_2 \leq \epsilon \| b \|_2
\end{align*}
holds with probability $99/100$. The algorithm runs in $O( mn \mathrm{poly} (1/\epsilon) + n^3 )$ time?